# Using multivariable LSTM to predict only certain values

Tags: python, pandas, lstm

Okay, so, the question might be a bit tricky.

For a project I'm working on, I'm supposed to predict sales values from a store for certain products. Easy enough, I've done two functional models that, analyzing the sales over the past 10 years of a single product, is capable of predicting the future sales.

However, here's where it gets complicated:

My dataframe looks something like this:

```
df={month : [...], id : [...], n_sales : [...], group : [...], brand : [...]}
```

Id refers to the product, whereas group refers to the type of product and brand is just the brand.

It's important to understand that, of course, a single id has only one group and one brand, contrary to them since they both can have multiple different id's.

Finally, my data is organized by month (ascendant) and by ID (also ascendant).
Meaning that, let's say the store has 50 products (50 id's).

Then the first 50 rows of my dataset would be:

----**Date**----|--**Id**--|--**n_sales**--|......
2012-01-01  | 1 ......
2012-01-01  | 2 ......
2012-01-01  | 3 ......
......
2012-01-01  | 50 .....

Then the next 50 rows would be the respective sales of each product for the month **2012-02-01** and so on until now.

I'm sorry if this is confusing, I'm trying to explain it as clear as I can.

Okay, I'm almost done. It's understandable that, if I isolate a single product, it would be easy to analyze the data.
I could just plot the sales from the known months alongside the sales from the prediction.

However, in order to make a more accurate prediction, I was asked to run a LSTM multivariable model, meaning that I have to take into account both group and brand. This, of course, means training my model with all the data from all the products. This is better understood with an example:

Let's say a new ice cream from Nestle was just created last November. Only analyzing the sales from that ice cream could not predict that the sales in summer will go up, since the only data the model would have is the few sales made in the cold months.
Nonetheless, if I analyze all the products, LSTM would know that, products from Nestle sell considerably more in summer and would take this into account when making the prediction for this new product.

And there's the problem, so now, getting to the question, how can I analyze all the data, from all the products but **only** get the predictions from a single Id?

Note: It has to be with LSTM, other models aren't an option.

And to anyone making it this far, even if you are not able to help, thank you for reading such a mess!